# Containable not working correctly with deep association

Tags: php, cakephp, model, associations

I have a Produto(Product) model that belongsTo Titulo(Title). 
Pedido(Order) hasMany Itens and the Itens belongsTo Produto(Product).
however, after I use find(all) using the model Pedido containing Itens with Produto, the next find of Produto, the contain nor the recursive function works, here is an example:

```
        $proModel = ClassRegistry::Init('Produto');
        pr($proModel->find('first', array('conditions' => array('pro_cod' => 650), 'contain' => 'Titulo')));
        $cart = $pedModel->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array('ped_cod' => $cart['Pedido']['ped_cod']),
            'contain' => array(
                'Itens' => array(
                    'Produto' => array(
                        'Estadia' => array('Atributo', 'Numero'), 'Produtoplataformas'
                    ), 
                    'Troca', 'Locado', 'Tipo', 
                    'Locacao' => array('Plano', 'Itens')
                ),
                'Usuario'
            ),
            'recursive' => -1
        ));
        pr($proModel->find('first', array('conditions' => array('pro_cod' => 650), 'contain' => 'Titulo')));
        exit;
```

The first pr of $proModel->find works ok and prints the 'Titulo' that is associated, however, after the $pedModel->find, the very same $proModel->find doesn't print the 'Titulo' association.
I have no afterFind method.

**EDIT:**

I pr($proModel->belongsTo) and it changes after $pedModel->find. All associations vanish except the ones used in the contain section of $pedModel->find.
If I use a new Produto instead of ClassRegistry::Init('Produto'), it worked fine, but I guess this is not a good thing, right?
This sucks.

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version! Also in case this is not a known bug, I doubt that you'll get much help here, as there probably won't be many people willing to take on the tedious task of trying to reproduce the problem.

Comment: 1. Please tell us which version of Cake 2. Do you have debug on? If not set it to level 2 in config.  3. Swap pr() for debug() it will tell you more. 4. If you can't have debug on try clearing the cache in tmp. I have had problems similar to this in the past where the cache was causing problems, (though if you have debug 2 on it will clear the cache for you).

Comment: I was using cakephp 2.6.1, just switched to 2.6.1, and debug is level 2. It prints the same thing. Where can I get help? this is troubling me badly because it was all working, I just added that $pedModel->find and it all came to madness.

Comment: I meant, I was using 2.6.1 and switch to the newest, that is 2.6.2.

Comment: Please do not copy your SO questions to the CakePHP bug tracker. Report _fixable problems_ not "my code is broken".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug of CakePHP:
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/5992

You can't have same aliases inside the contain block.

One of the staff said it was a limitation, for me, it is a bug, since it, at least, didn't throw an error.